# Combining several granger causality tests

Tags: time-series, p-value, granger-causality

I have two time series and I am testing them with gragner. The problem is that it's not continuous, one timeseries is constant while the other one has half of the time data. Example: yes = has data, no = doesn't have data

series1 = yes,yes,yes,yes
series2 = yes,no,yes,no

What I am doing is that I am checking granger causality for 0,0 then 2,2 then 4,4 periods and skipping the periods that don't have 1:1 data.

Can I average the F statistics and p values or is this bad math?

Comment: If you're careful about specifying your population, you can average the F statistics and p values in a mathematically rigorous way. But it will remain an important question of whether such aggregated statistics tell you what you want to know. What is it you want to know by aggregating multiple Granger tests?

Comment: the overall granger causality of the 2 series when they happen together